# MySQL: How to disable automatic conversion of invalid dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I disable automatic conversion of date/datetime columns of invalid date to 0000-00-00?
In my my.cnf I insert this line:

```
sql-mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
```

in sections:

```
[client]
[mysqld]
```

Mysql server run on Debian server, and Mysql version is 5.1.63-0+squeeze1.

When I execute INSERT or UPDATE with PHP, invalid values are converted in 0000-00-00.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

table create:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `versioni` (
  `cod_versione` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_versione`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

insert statement that raise error in customer DB, otherwise in development are converted in '0000-00-00':

`INSERT INTO versioni (cod_versione, data) VALUES (67, '2014-04-101 00:00:00');`

Comment: Are you asking for MySQL to raise an error when you try to insert an invalid date, or to allow the invalid date to be entered in to the database?

Comment: Have you restarted MySQL after you made changes to my.cnf?

Comment: I would like MySQL to raise an error, actually mysql convert invalid dates.

Comment: @fancyPants Yes I have restarted MySQL service with `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` command

Comment: And if you do `show variables like 'sql_mode';` what is its output?

Comment: @fancyPants this is result: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this behaviour. When I insert a date like '2014-01-00' it errors like expected.

Comment: Can you give an example of an insert which behaves like this and the structure/deifnition of the column?  In my quick tests locally I get an error if the date string is invalid for both DATE and DATETIME columns

Comment: I have edited my question with table structure and insert statement

Comment: With PhpMyAdmin Insert fails and raise me error, but when I use my procedure error are not show like other errors (like foreign key error)

Comment: Using your table structure and query posted above I get an error (in MySQL Workbench): `12:20:18 INSERT INTO versioni (cod_versione, data) VALUES (67, '2014-04-101 00:00:00') Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2014-04-101 00:00:00' for column 'data' at row 1 0.000 sec`

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could just try not inserting invalid dates...

But if you must, you should use a `CHAR(10)` column instead of a `DATE` column, as this will give you the... freedom you seek.

---

Alternatively, just use PHP functions, such as `checkdate`, to validate input before throwing it at the database ;)

Comment: I would errors to prevent errors during update of db of our customers

Comment: He said he wanted it to raise an error.  Char(10) will just allow you to save the string even if it is an invalid date (as long as it is the right length)

Comment: @Adam When did OP say he wanted it to raise an error? Now, when did I post my answer? Okay then.

Comment: @Niet: yeah, wasn't meaning to "blame" you in that sense.  Just pointing out the answer doesn't fity the (updated) requirements

Comment: I can't use PHP checkdate because date is in a SQL script

Comment: @webs86 You tagged your question [tag:php]. You even say "when I execute [...] with PHP".

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I use PHP mysql_query function to execute SQL and the error will not shown in development DB (there is 0000-00-00 in the table row), but customer database raise me the error

Comment: Okay then. *Before calling `mysql_query`*, use `checkdate` on the date to ensure it is valid.

Comment: I can't use PHP checkdate because date is in a SQL script (an .SQL file, in pure SQL)

Comment: Then why is `mysql_query` involved at all?

Comment: PHP read external SQL file row by row and execute SQL statements

Comment: Then surely you can parse for... wait, why does your `.sql` file even have invalid dates in the first place?